# Facebook group management API availability

Tags: facebook

is there a way in the Facebook API to manage groups members (add members or delete members) in closed group because i can't find anything related to this on the Facebook developers website.

Thanks

Comment: There is no API for that

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for general groups, you can only do that with App/Game groups - information about that are in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/group/members/